# Is it faster to access a java list (arraylist) compared to accessing the same data in a mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, arraylist

I have the MYSQL database in the local machine where I'm running the java program from.

I plan create a array list of all the entries of a particular table. From this point on wards I will not access the database to get a particular entry in the table, instead I will use the array list created. Is this going to be faster or slower compared to accessing the database to grab a particular entry in the table?

Please note that the table I'm interested has about 2 million entries.

Thank you.

More info : I need only two fields. 1 of type Long and 1 of type String. The index of the table is Long , not int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's going to be much slower, because to find an element in an ArrayList, you've to scan sequentially the ArrayList until your element is found.

It can be faster, for a few hundreds entry, because you don't have the connection overhead, but with two millions entry, MySQL is going to win, provided that you create the correct indexes. Only retrieve the rows that you actually need each time.

Why are you thinking to do this? Are you experiencing slow queries?

To find out, in your my.cnf activate the slow query log, by uncommenting (or adding) the following lines.

```
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
log_slow_queries    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
```

Then see which queries take a long time, and run them with EXPLAIN in front, consider to add index where the explain command tells you that is not using indexes, or just post a new question with your CREATE TABLE statement and your example query to optimize.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer :) , apparently I have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer -_-'

Comment: It is to leave time to others, who may give a better answer. [Read here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) to find out why MySQL is faster than a scan row by row, especially on big tables.

Comment: I'm thinking about doing this because the program takes too long to complete. About 6 hours.

Comment: ok, I've updated the answer with a suggestion to tackle the problem

Answer (score 1):

This question is too vague, and can easily go either way depending on:

1. How many fields in each record, how big are the fields?
2. What kind of access are you going to perform? Text search? Sequential?

For example, if each records consists of a couple bytes of data it's much faster to store them all in-memory (not necessarily an ArrayList though). You may want to put them into a TreeSet for example.

Comment: what do you mean by what kind of access? I'm using select field1, field2 from TABLE

Comment: Are you going to be searching for 1 record based on a user input string, or are you going to be iterating sequentially over all the records (ie updating stock prices).

Comment: Also, if text based search is what you are doing then I'd recommend using something like Lucene to index the text field, that makes it much faster to look something up than a db query.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you will do with the data. If you just wanted a few rows, only those should be fetched from the DB. If you know that you need ALL the data, go ahead and load the whole table into java if it can fit in memory. What will you do with it after? Sequencial or random reading? Will data be changed? A Map or Set could be a faster alternative depending on how the collection will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is faster or slower is measurable. Time it. It is definitely faster to work with structures stored in memory than it is to work with data tables located on the disk. That is if you have enough memory and if you do not have 20 users running the same process at the same time.

How do you access the data? Do you have an integer index?

Comment: I do not have an integer index. The index is Long

Comment: It is the same! If it is contiguous you can access your ArrayList via this as an index. If not consider using a HashTable instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, accessing an array list is much much faster than accessing a data base. Accessing memory is much more faster than accessing a hard disk.
If the number of entries in the array is big and I guess it is, then you need to consider using a "direct access" data structure such as a HashMap which will act as a database table where you have values referenced by their keys